# issue with the result of javascript for of loop code

Tags: javascript, loops, for-of-loop

i tried a code to upper case each letter at the beginning of a word on an array of strings both by
traditional for loop and for of loop but it didn't work with the for of loop.

```
let days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];

/*for (var index = 0 ; index < days.length ; index++)
{
let test = Array.from(days[index]);
//console.log(test);
let x = days[index].charCodeAt(0)-32;
//console.log(x);
test[0] = String.fromCharCode(x);
//console.log(test);
days[index] = test.join("");
}*/



for (let index of days)
{
    //console.log(index);
    let test = Array.from(index);
    //console.log(test);
    let x = index.charCodeAt(0)-32;
    //console.log(x);
    test[0] = String.fromCharCode(x);
    //console.log(test);
    index = test.join("");
}
console.log(days);
```

the upper loop worked perfectely but the lower one didn't

Comment: `index = test.join("");` -  what is it supposed to do in your opinion?

Comment: You seem to twist and turn trying to update a string, but you are only reassigning to a variable which you then ignore. BTW: strings are immutable.

Comment: `for/of` iterates the actual items, not their indexes.

Comment: it is concatinating the array of charachters into a string @Konrad

Comment: the word index here refers to the item itself ,my bad i should have named it day instead of index @bbbbbbbbb

Comment: i am not really getting your point @trincot ,how am i ignoring the variable ? ,and how are arrays immutable -->the traditional for loop which almost contains the same code worked

Comment: You are replacing your `index` variable with a new thing entirely. `=` is no concatenation operator

Comment: I didn't say *arrays* were immutable. And you are ignoring the value of `index` after you have assigned `test.join("")` to it, because nothing happens with it after that, so why would you make that assignment? It is useless.

Comment: isn't the change to the value of iterator index gonna reflect on the array itself ? ,how should the code be ? @trincot

Comment: No, that seems to be the core misconception in your question. See the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a misconception is at the base of your question: assigning to the loop variable of a `for...of` loop will *not* modify the array you are looping over. An assignment to a variable is just that: the variable changes -- not the array where that variable initially got a value from.

So in your case, `index = test.join("");` will not change anything to the array `days`. There is no "memory" in `index` that knows that it got its value from the `days` array -- `index` is just a variable like any other. Once you realise this, it also becomes clear that this assignment achieves nothing useful, as nothing more happens with this `index` variable.

In the old-school `for` loop the corresponding assignment is to `days[i]`. That is not an assignment to a *variable*, but to a *property*! That is a whole different story. Assigning to a property will mutate the object that owns that property. In this case that object is an array, and the property is an index. Assigning to a *variable* does not change a data structure.<sup>*</sup>

A `for..of` loop is not the right tool if you want to mutate an array. As alternative you could use `.map` and assign the resulting (new!) array back to `days`:

```js
let days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];

days = days.map(day => day[0].toUpperCase() + day.slice(1));

console.log(days);
```

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>**Assigning to a *variable* does not change a data structure.**: There are some exceptions to this rule when variables are true *aliases* for properties, like the global `var` variables in a browser context are aliases for `window` properties, and in sloppy mode the elements of the `arguments` array are aliases for the individual function arguments. But none of those exceptions apply here.</sub>